# How to use python code with Flutter application?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I wanna to make a chatbot app with fluter, so i will use flutter only to create the user interface, and i wanna to interact my flutter app with python, so i will receive the question from flutter app and i will send it to python function, and this function should return the answer , and in flutter i will display it to the screen.

Hint:

1. I made the UI with flutter.
2. I created python function "It uses Neural Network".
3. I wanna to use python as a function only, i will pass the questions to it, and it should return the answer.
   ...

so i need now to know how to call my python function in flutter app???
[image: image here]

Comment: [Information on this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages) may be useful.

Comment: Hey, did you find the answers? I m stuck onto the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [starflut package](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut)

It supports flutter to interact with other scripting languages such as python, java, ruby, golang, rust, etc. It is easy to use, supports android and ios platform.

Visit this [link](https://medium.com/@pyzimos/flutter-chatbot-with-python-flask-backend-heroku-deployment-706baafbb8f1), the article might help you

Comment: Is there any way easier than that, Hint: i just wanna to use python as a function only, i will pass the questions to it, and it should return the answer. any other the things about the chatbot , i will handle it with flutter and dart

Comment: Note that Starflut claims to be open-source, but it is not: https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to run python code in flutter is to use [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) package, you just need to do configuration and put your code inside `Chaquopy.executeCode()` method, the best thing about this package is its simplicity and allows users to integrate even python packages.