# How to use Flutter as UI for application written in python?

Tags: python, flutter

I've been working with desktop app written using python, pyQT and QT. UI is defined in QML and business logic is python-based. Now, I would like to start using Flutter for UI, but I would prefer to retain existing python codebase for logic, instead of rewriting everything in Dart, which would be huge effort.

Another thread [How to use python code with Flutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742897/how-to-use-python-code-with-flutter-application) pointed me to starflut, however examples don't look like anything which could be used for complex inter-working between model and view.

So, my question is: Is it possible to have Flutter View which uses python Model? If so, what are good practices?

Comment: One idea would be to build a REST api in something like Django or Flask, using your already designed models, etc and from there fetch it directly from your Flutter app

Comment: @Josh For a *desktop app*?!